# adjoint operator in Sobolev space

Tags: functional-analysis, sobolev-spaces

Let $g\in H_0^1(\Omega)\cap W^{2,\infty}(\Omega),$ and let us define the operator $B : y \to g y$ from $H:=H_0^1(\Omega)\cap H^2(\Omega)$ to $H$, which we endowed with inner product : $<u,v>_H =<u,v>_{L^2(\Omega)} + <\Delta u,\Delta v>_{L^2(\Omega)}$,

I want to explicit the adjoint operator $B^*$ of $B$ in $(H,<,>)$.

Comment: Please give some description of what you've tried, what you don't understand and what specifically you want help to do. "Explicit" isn't a verb; do you mean "explicitly find"?

Comment: I used the definition, ie, I tried to write $<By,z>$ in the form $<y,B^*z>$, but I can't obtain it explicitly. Does exist any formula concerning the Laplacian that can help to do this?